# Why did this low quality review get invalidated?

Tags: support

See [this timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40288637/timeline#review_14117748). Approximately 1 hour ago, first post, late answer, and low quality reviews where all either completed or invalidated. Why was the low quality review invalidated? My "Not an Answer" flag was marked as helpful, but the post still exists?

This "answer" is still NAA.

Comment: A moderator dismissed the flag as helpful manually and took no further action. Since there was no active flag to warrant it being in review, the task was invalidated a few minutes later. I'm assuming you *actually* want to know why the answer wasn't deleted, though.

Comment: @animuson I'm assuming it was left around, because it could be considered helpful in diagnosing the error, but it's worded like a question? Still seems like content that should be removed IMO.

Comment: @animuson Wouldn't it be better to add "invalidated by a moderator", or is it implied directly (whenever there's an invalidated and no edits,etc)?

Comment: @BhargavRao It's simply too complicated to go through a post's entire history to determine if a *moderator's* actions caused a post to no longer qualify for review versus something else. There are way too many factors that can cause this to happen, and it doesn't actually tell anyone the information they actually want to know: why.

Comment: @animuson Thanks, Understood. Perhaps we need to look out for more posts that were invalidated to discover all those factors. 1 down, Too many to go.

Comment: If a flag is "helpful", moderators should not be taking "no further action". That is antithetical.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, That is not, necessarily, true. You could raise a flag for something that looks strange which might be the result of actions by other which should not be taken. You raise the flag, yet don't have the tools to fully investigate the cause of the situation.  After investigating, the moderator finds that there is nothing untoward going on. If the situation was sufficiently unusual to warrant a flag to have it looked into in greater depth than can be done by a normal user, then that flag was "helpful", even though it resulted in "no further action".

Comment: The post is now deleted; I'm not sure if the question or answer was the part deleted.

Comment: Can a 10k user/mod post the deleted answer?

Answer (score 4):

That review was invalidated by (I assume) a scheduled job at 16:39:20, a few minutes after I dismissed the flags on it at 16:36:01.

For reference, the answer:

> [do you have submit button in your .aspx page ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24410733/1849664)

It's borderline, but in my judgment at the time (and now) it *is* an attempt to answer. It looks like a horrible one, and it's probably wrong, but I have no reason to believe that the person typing into the box didn't intend to answer the question. Yes, it had a question mark. We're humans, we can infer a solution from a question.

I probably *should* have just declined the flags. Instead, I took the charitable path and marked them as helpful, given the borderline-ness of that answer. I won't overrule the community's decision to delete it, but I do stand by my decision *not* to delete it.

Comment: These are cases where, IMO, flags should be "disputed", and not "declined". Don't have it count against them, but choose to take no action. It would have also prevented this post from ever being created.

Comment: @FrankerZ That's exactly what happened here. We don't really have a way to dispute NAA flags; marking them helpful is the closest thing we can do.

Comment: Perhaps put in a feature request to allow mods to dispute all flags?

Comment: I must not be human then. I'm not able to tell from that answer whether it intended to suggest that a submit should be added, that a submit button should *not* be added, or whether it merely asked in order to propose a workaround through a submit button. For questions, we have an "unclear what you're asking" close option. Closing doesn't delete the question, but does pressure the OP to edit it into something intelligible. For answers, if this doesn't fit under NAA (which I think you're right about), something similar would be useful. Downvoting isn't enough with sympathy upvotes.

Comment: Related question, @Undo. What do you feel in [this case](//stackoverflow.com/posts/40362374/revisions) (see the first revision)? It ended with a question mark and we could have somewhat edited that post to make it look like an answer. Something like "The  keywords (item, magnitude) seem not to be methods in astropy units quantity. It must be a specially neutered version". This would look perfect. But is it really an answer? No, It was a comment directed to this [post](//stackoverflow.com/a/9403502). So,  the question is, Where do we draw the line? (Or should mods use "move to comments" more?)