# When is NAA actually not an answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Recently, I found [this post](//stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14153415) in the VLQ queue. It had 2 delete votes, and a response of "This does not provide an answer to the question...". In [a similar circumstance](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337040/why-did-this-low-quality-review-get-invalidated), my NAA was marked as helpful but the post was left up by the moderator who viewed it. This changed my opinion on these "half answers" that may be worded with a question at the end, because some information in it can be helpful. In this particular circumstance, jsl even provided a statement which could lead the viewer towards the correct answer.

What should the course of action be for these? My opinion is that because it does in some way attempt to answer the question, this should have been left around, and was deleted incorrectly.

So far, the community has been split about this. Some feel that it should be converted to a comment, and some feel that it should be left and downvoted. I'd like a definitive answer (If possible), on how (as a community), these types of answers should be handled. As @JonClements decided, this "answer" was moved to a comment. If this is the case, could the VLQ reviewers have a way to convert these to comments, so that we don't miss possible pertinent information?

For reference, the answer:

[image]

Comment: I just wish people wouldn't word these like a suggestion or guess instead of an answer. I know that technically the answers *are* suggestions but the uncertainty makes it read like they don't intend for it to be an answer.

Comment: I wonder if meagar just didn't realize it was an answer in the form of a question?

Comment: It seems quite easy to edit this answer such that it does not look like question anymore.

Comment: @DidierL Sure, but answers aren't supposed to be guesses. That's what makes Stack Overflow better than all those crappy forums: to find your answer, you don't have to try a whole bunch of guesses that people spent about three seconds on.

Comment: *Maybe* they're just trying to weasel out of downvotes. ;-) Either they should be confident in their answer and just post it, or post a comment until they *are* confident.  Don't try to have it both ways.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Which is a fantastic justification for downvoting it, but that's not grounds for deletion.

Comment: Now it shows deleted by @JonClements. What is going on?

Comment: @FrankerZ He converted it to a comment on the question.

Comment: Maybe it's just time that SE opens up [comment moderation](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6?m=33770364#33770364) to users.

Comment: @BhargavRao I've updated the question, and included some of the discussion.

Comment: Yeah, It looks like the moderators themselves are in a confused situation. Undo clearly mentions that it is an answer in the post that you linked http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337129/4099593

Comment: These review queues induce a horrible tunnel-vision problem.  The answer is a guess.  Why did he have to guess?  **Look at the question**.  Doesn't say squat about the dbase schema, nobody is ever going to Google it, nothing but a useless forum question.  So get rid of the question, that solves **two** problems.  Moderators won't delete questions like that, it is up to *you* to do the Right Thing.